# How do I colorize a texture with libGDX?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, textures

I'm working on a libGDX implementation for my library which draws ASCII tiles to create a text GUI. My current Swing + `BufferedImage` implementation looks like this:

[image]

This works by copying parts of a grayscale texture which has CP437 characters on it and transforming them by adding color to each pixel.

My problem is that my libGDX implementation does not work for some reason:

[image]

What I have tried is this:

```
    val backend: TextureRegion = region.getBackend()

    val texture = backend.texture
    if (!texture.textureData.isPrepared) {
        texture.textureData.prepare()
    }
    val pixmap = texture.textureData.consumePixmap()
    (0 until backend.regionWidth).forEach { x ->
        (0 until backend.regionHeight).forEach { y ->
            val color = Color(pixmap.getPixel(backend.regionX + x, backend.regionY + y))

            val ax = color.a
            var rx = color.r
            var gx = color.g
            var bx = color.b
            rx *= r
            gx *= g
            bx *= b
            if (ax < 50) {
                pixmap.drawPixel(backend.regionX + x, backend.regionY + y, textCharacter.getBackgroundColor().toAWTColor().rgb)
            } else {
                pixmap.drawPixel(backend.regionX + x, backend.regionY + y, Color(rx, gx, bx, ax).toIntBits())
            }
        }
    }

    return region
```

I know that I am missing something but I just can't figure out what the problem is here. I've tried with various options like copying the `TextureRegion` but I can't get this to work.

My other implementation uses `BufferedImage`s and it just works:

```
    val r = textCharacter.getForegroundColor().getRed().toFloat() / 255
    val g = textCharacter.getForegroundColor().getGreen().toFloat() / 255
    val b = textCharacter.getForegroundColor().getBlue().toFloat() / 255

    val backend: BufferedImage = region.getBackend()
    (0 until backend.width).forEach { x ->
        (0 until backend.height).forEach { y ->
            val ax = backend.colorModel.getAlpha(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            var rx = backend.colorModel.getRed(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            var gx = backend.colorModel.getGreen(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            var bx = backend.colorModel.getBlue(backend.raster.getDataElements(x, y, null))
            rx = (rx * r).toInt()
            gx = (gx * g).toInt()
            bx = (bx * b).toInt()
            if (ax < 50) {
                backend.setRGB(x, y, textCharacter.getBackgroundColor().toAWTColor().rgb)
            } else {
                backend.setRGB(x, y, (ax shl 24) or (rx shl 16) or (gx shl 8) or (bx shl 0))
            }
        }
    }
    return region
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Color.toIntBits returns ABGR format. Pixmap.drawPixel takes rgba8888

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#drawPixel-int-int-int-
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.html#toIntBits--

Use Color.rgba8888(color) instead.